# How to request Waypoints in Google Map Distance Matrix API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use Google Map [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) but I also want to include Waypoints in it.

Distance matrix take 2 inputs only as it takes list of Starting Points and list of Destinations points. I want to include Starting Point, Destination Point and Final Destination Point.
So it should show distance matrix of A -> B -> C

How can I incorporate that ?

Comment: It doesn't look like the API allows for a way-point request, although, through whatever language you are using to grab the XML, you should easily be able to parse one request and then another. If you are able to post the question with some code that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyKarbowski at the moment I don't have any sourcecode created. Just trying to find out if there is any alternate solution for including waypoints then I will make the sourcecode.

Answer (score 5):

Use **A** and **B** as origins.

Use **B** and **C** as destinations.

Your response should contain **A->B**, **A->C**, **B->B**, **B->C** distances.

Extract & sum **A->B** and **B->C** to receive your target distance with a single API call.

Comment: So if I have route A -> B -> C -> D, I must make A, B, and C as origins?

Comment: This is great but it will cost me two more elements that I don't need.
Namely A->C and B->B which are not free

Comment: eladzaa and @JoshDM any idea how to make a single call for that?

Comment: @Noman I'm just an editor.